# Mysql Deeper Joins

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

As result says:
 
I want to select all data from **tbl_appointment** where **user_id=100**,
joining **doctor_name** from **tbl_doctor**,
plus
I want to join the third table **tbl_document**
Where 
**total_type1** is **count(document_type)** where **document_type=1** for each user_id and doctor_id pair
**total_type2** is **count(document_type)** where **document_type=2** for each user_id and doctor_id pair
**total_type3** is **count(document_type)** where **document_type=3** for each user_id and doctor_id pair

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_appointment AS main
JOIN(
    SELECT doctor_id AS d_id,doctor_name FROM tbl_doctor
)doctor
ON man.doctor_id=doctor.d_id
where user_id=100
```

i am confused to join my third table, please help me

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why new SQL users always try to join subqueries instead of just joining table directly. Is there some tutorial out there that is telling them to do that?

In any case, you can join your third table just as you would your second table. Since documents might not exist for every doctor (I don't know your system), I've used a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for that table.

```
SELECT
    APPT.user_id,
    DR.doctor_id,
    APPT.appointment,
    DR.doctor_name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DOC.document_type = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_type1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DOC.document_type = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_type2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DOC.document_type = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_type3
FROM tbl_appointment AS APPT
INNER JOIN tbl_doctor DR ON DR.doctor_id = APPT.doctor_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_document DOC ON DOC.doctor_id = DR.doctor_id
WHERE
    APPT.user_id = 100
GROUP BY
    APPT.user_id,
    DR.doctor_id,
    APPT.appointment,
    DR.doctor_name
```

Looking back at your results, I realize that you're trying to count the number of each document type. You can do this with the `SUM(CASE...)` statements that I have above, although this will not help if a document type of 4 is added. You're might be better off including the `document_type` in the result set, adding that to the `GROUP BY` list, and just calculating a `COUNT(*)`. You'll get separate rows for each document type, but it's more readily expandable as long as your front end handles that form of the results.

Answer (score 0):

I like this style of sql:

```
select tbl_appointment.*,
tbl_doctor.doctor_name
(select count(*) from tbl_document where tbl_document.user_id = tbl_appointment.user_id and tbl_document.doctor_id = tbl_appointment.doctor_id and document_type=1) as total_type1,
(select count(*) from tbl_document where tbl_document.user_id = tbl_appointment.user_id and tbl_document.doctor_id = tbl_appointment.doctor_id and document_type=2) as total_type2,
(select count(*) from tbl_document where tbl_document.user_id = tbl_appointment.user_id and tbl_document.doctor_id = tbl_appointment.doctor_id and document_type=3) as total_type3
from tbl_appointment
join tbl_doctor doc on (tbl_doctor.doctor_id = tbl_appointment.doctor_id)
```

You do not need to join third table actually. You can use subquery select count...